# Binding UITextView to MutableProperty

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

How can I bind a UITextView's text property to a MutableProperty, e.g.

```
let property = MutableProperty<String>("")
commentTextView.text <~ property
```

This just gives me the error

```
Binary operator '<~' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String!' and 'MutableProperty<String>'
```

but I don't  understand why.

Is there a documentation somewhere of how the bindings work in ReactiveSwift?

I checked  a couple of potential sources, such as the very brief documentation on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) and [reactivecocoa.io](http://reactivecocoa.io/reactiveswift/docs/latest/), but after reading them I get the feeling that ReactiveSwift is not capable of doing this.

I also read another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155298/use-of-unresolved-operator/41326971), but the accepted answer does not seem to apply in this case or is  wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a syntactical misunderstanding that was not so clear to me from the sparse ReactiveSwift documentation.
One has to add a .reactive in between:

```
let property = MutableProperty<String>("")
commentTextView.reactive.text <~ property
```